# How to slice list items in Django Template using javascript (or similar)

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates, chart.js

I'm using chartJs with some data that I want the user to be able to dynamically change the number of items charted.

Currently, I'm working on Django template with data calculated in a view in Python/Django that comes in a plain list (data: [5133.85, 1103.59, 1837.62, 378.90, 467.29, 107.35, 147.17, 0, ], for instance)

The Django template code for the data of a dataset of my chart is as follows (which is listing the last 3 values of the list) and is working fine:

`data: [{% for data in list|slice:'-3:' %}{{ data|unlocalize }}, {% endfor %}]`

(the way this is written could be improved, I guess, but that's not the purpose of this post)

My question is:

- I want the user to be able to change the number of items of the list, therefore, the number of columns of the chart, ie, that slice parameter above (-3). How can I do that using a javascript function?

Something like `<a href='' onClick='changeColumnsTo(5)'>Last 5 values</a>` changing the parameter of the slice command in `{% for data in list|slice:'-3:' %}{{ data|unlocalize }}, {% endfor %}`

I know I could solve the problem getting Django's views.py calculate the list with the N values I want, reloading the page. But I don't want to upset my server with so much unnecessary calls.

I wonder if, instead of a javascript based solution, there is one other way of doing this (never reloading the page)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've just realized that I cannot use the slice parameter, since it would effectively slice the list.
I didn't explain it in the first message but my goal is that the user can change the number of columns he wants to see, over and over.
If I slice the list, I can no longer get the sliced data...

Nevertheless, I still want the user to change the number of (last) columns in the graph.

Thanks you all!